# open source libraries for facebook ,emails ,IM

Tags: java, email, facebook

Can any one suggest me a open source library for
1)By which i can write on facebook wall of my friends? 
2)By which i can send emails to the contacts in my fiends list of

1. MSN
2. 2yahoo
3. 3gmail
4. 4 etc

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at - [Facebook Java API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/).

**EDIT:**

Here is link that describes steps to publish on [Facebook Wall](http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/facebook-java-api-example-to-publish-on-wall/). If you are wokring with web then look at - [Tag Library for calling Facebook API functions in a JSP Page](http://www.socialjava.com/).